# I want to rearrange the ObservableCollection which is completed in nature

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, mvvm, observablecollection

I am working on WPF MVVM.

I am fetching the records from database and
I have binded ObservableCollection to xaml Itemsource.

Fetch List Code :

```
private async void getKYCUserDetails()
{
var data = _DataService.Client;
                var AllKYCUserList = await data.For<vwKYCUserDetails>().FindEntriesAsync();
                lstTempKYCUserDetails= new ObservableCollection<vwKYCUserDetails>(AllKYCUserList);
}
```

I want to rearrange the ObservableCollection such that System must show clients whose details are complete in nature on top of the report so user can act as per JIT approach.

Xaml :

```
   <syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dgKYCUser" 
                                               ItemsSource="{Binding Path = lstTempKYCUserDetails,Mode=TwoWay}"   
                                           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}"                                                   
                                           NavigationMode="Row"
                                           SelectionMode="Multiple"
                                           ColumnSizer="Auto"
                                           HeaderRowHeight="30"
                                           AllowFiltering="True"                                                   
                                           AllowSorting="True"                                                                                     
                                           AllowGrouping="True" 
                                           ShowGroupDropArea="True" 
                                           HeaderStyle="{StaticResource headerStyle}" 
                                           AllowResizingColumns="True"
                                           AllowDraggingColumns="True"
                                           AllowDrop="True"
                                           AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                           Foreground="#3e4345"
                                           AllowEditing="True"
                                           FrozenColumnCount="2"
                                           BorderBrush="Red"
                                           Background="White"
                                           >
```

I have multiple columns in sfDatagrid in that I am converting boolean value to image using Converter and show image.

e.g

```
                            <syncfusion:GridImageColumn 
                        ImageHeight="20" Width="30" ShowHeaderToolTip="True"
                        MappingName="bMobileVerify" HeaderText="Mobile Verified" 
                       ValueBinding="{Binding bMobileVerify, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"                                                        
                    />
```

The ImageConverter Code :

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((Boolean)value == true)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format(@"..\..\Images\{0}", "check.png"), UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else if ((Boolean)value == false)
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format(@"..\..\Images\{0}", "crosssqr.png"), UriKind.Relative));
        }
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(string.Format(@"..\..\Images\{0}", "TransparentBackground.png"), UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image: UI Grid Image]

I want the records which has most ticks should on the top likewise it should have  arranged, I don't have any clue how to rearrange it.

Comment: can you not sort the data from the DB by count of ticks desc

Comment: Even If I count the ticks by boolean value I didn't understand how should I get an optimal solution to rearrange list.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ICollectionView

ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstTempKYCUserDetails);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("tickscounter", ListSortDirection.Descending));

Comment: Thank You oz shalom.

Comment: I didn't understand how should I use the "tickscounter" will it be in a foreach loop.

Comment: you should add to your model a new field that sum the ticks. the ICollectionView advantage is that it doesn't change the original list but only the UI

Comment: There will be different counter number for different clients. So how I should use tickscounter in viewmodel , as it will be vary for different clients.